# How do you parameterize Limit and Offset in a Snowflake Procedure?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How do you parameterize Limit and Offset in a Snowflake Procedure? When calling this procedure like so:  CALL GETJOBS ('test1', 3, 3);

The response is: "Failed: SQL compilation error:\nInvalid row count ':2' in limit clause"

It doesnt appear to be accepting limit and offset parameters.

```html
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "GETJOBS"("CODES" VARCHAR(16777216), "LIMIT" FLOAT, "OFFSET" FLOAT)
RETURNS VARIANT
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS '
        var sql = snowflake.createStatement({ 
                    sqlText: `select jobnbr 
                              from jobs
                              where islocked = 1                            
                              order by jobnbr 
                              limit :2 offset :3;`,
                    binds: [CODES, LIMIT, OFFSET].map(function(x){return x === undefined ? null : x})                   
        });

        try {
            var results = sql.execute();            
            var columns = sql.getColumnCount();         
            var array = [];         
            while (results.next()) {
                let object = new Object;                
                var current = 1;
                while (current <= columns) {
                    object[results.getColumnName(current).toString()] = results.getColumnValue(current);
                    current++;
                }
                array.push(object);             
            }
            return array;
        }
        catch (err) {           
            return "Failed: " + err;
        }       
        return null;
    ';
```

Comment: As far as I can see this is not supported, same for **TOP n**. You can probably create an [Idea](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-Search-Create-Vote-Follow-Ideas) for it as it makes sense to have this functionality.

Comment: Interesting.  When dealing with a large result set (20K json objects) how can we support such a response size?  I was thinking using limit/offset and having calling app implement pagination.  If passing those parameters are not supported is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution can be to change the following:

```
var sql = snowflake.createStatement({ 
                    sqlText: `select jobnbr 
                              from jobs
                              where islocked = 1                            
                              order by jobnbr 
                              limit :2 offset :3;`,
                    binds: [CODES, LIMIT, OFFSET].map(function(x){return x === undefined ? null : x})                   
        });
```

to something like:

```
var sql_cmd = "select jobnbr from jobs where islocked = 1 order by jobnbr limit " + LIMIT + " offset " + OFFSET;
var sql = snowflake.createStatement({ 
                    sqlText: sql_cmd,
                    binds: [CODES].map(function(x){return x === undefined ? null : x})                   
        });
```

but this would not use bindings for LIMIT and OFFSET. It would still work when calling stored proc like:

```
CALL GETJOBS ('test1', 3, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach using  `QUALIFY` and `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
var sql = snowflake.createStatement({ 
            sqlText: `select jobnbr 
                      from jobs
                      where islocked = :1
                      qualify row_number() over(order by jobnbr) between :2 and :3                           
                              order by jobnbr`,
            binds: [CODES, OFFSET + 1, LIMIT + OFFSET + 1].map(function(x){return x === undefined ? null : x})                   
        });
```